# Broadcom BCM4318 Wireless LAN Controller ISSUE

Tags: 13.04, wireless, networking, laptop, screen

Basically, I installed Ubtunu from scratch the other day. It was working fine, the Ethernet was easy. I just plugged it in and off it went. Now today I did something stupid, thinking I could enable the wireless adaptor I went to Additional Drivers and saw that my INTERNAL Broadcom BCM4318 Wireless LAN Controller was not in use and like an idiot I put it into use and now I cant disable it.

I tried to go to 'Do not use this device' but it will say that it is applying changes for a very good while. But the this weird black screen flickers on for a second and now instead of my using my Ethernet, I know use my wireless adaptor which is broke and wont work with Ubuntu.

Anyone got any idea on how to disable this device forever so I can go back to using my Ethernet :/

Answer (score 0):

Are you still trying to connect to the wireless network in network manager and not the wired one? Try to connect to wired network in network manager. If you deleted or edited your wired configuration in wifi try setting that up again. OR you could have simply disconnected from it. Could help get to your network manager if you stated the flavor.

If you really do truly need to disable wireless a way to try to do that is rfkill http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Documentation/rfkill use rfkill list to find the device you want to block then rfkill block to block it if you really want to block wifi but you will still need a configured wired connection.